# How to pass vtkPolyData into vtkDijkstraGraphGeodesicPath?

Tags: vtk

This is what I have currently:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
polydata->SetPoints(path);
polydata->Modified();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkDijkstraGraphGeodesicPath> dijkstra =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDijkstraGraphGeodesicPath>::New();
dijkstra->SetInputData(polydata);
dijkstra->SetStartVertex(0);
dijkstra->SetEndVertex(1);
dijkstra->Update();
```

However, everytime it executes `Update()`, it returns `vector subscript out of range`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [vtkDijkstraGraphGeodesicPath](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDijkstraGraphGeodesicPath.html) documentation:

> Takes as input a polygonal mesh ...
>
> ...
>
> **Warning** The input polydata must have only triangle cells.

My guess is that your poly-data does not meet the necessary preconditions and is not a proper triangle mesh but just a point-set.

At least a call of `vtkPolyData::SetLines()` is needed to specify connections between vertices.